# group and summarize a column for unknown variables

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

This is an example for the data frame i have:

```
Location <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
Code <- c("70", "70", "60", "60", "60", "60", "50")
df <- data.frame(Location, Code)
```

I want to group and summarize the codes using this code:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(df$Code) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Number = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Percent = round((Number/sum(Number)*100))) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(Number))
```

I want this for every location though. And to add some difficutly; it is not clear, if there are different locations beforehand. The goal is to have an automatic function, that gives me the result for every location, by just using different data frames, where it is not clear, which locations are in it.

The result i am looking for is df2. df2 is for all locations though. i want a data frame, where the codes are listed and summarized by each location. so location "a" would have the codes 70 (2 times) and 60 (1 time) and the location "b" has 60 (3 times) and 50 (1 time).

I can not find a solution for this (only if i do it step by step, which i dont want)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use `$` in `dplyr` code. What is expected output that you are looking for? Do you want to add `Location` in `group_by` like `dplyr::group_by(Location, Code)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The result i am looking for is df2. df2 is for all locations though. i want a data frame, where the codes are listed and summarized by each location. so location "a" would have the codes 70 (2 times) and 60 (1 time) and the location "b" has 60 (3 times) and 50 (1 time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `count` number of enteries for each `Location` and `Code` and calculate ratio for each `Location` using `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Location, Code) %>%
  group_by(Location) %>%
  mutate(Percent = n/sum(n) * 100)

#  Location Code      n Percent
#  <chr>    <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#1 a        60        1    33.3
#2 a        70        2    66.7
#3 b        50        1    25  
#4 b        60        3    75
```

If we want data as separate column for each `Location`.

```
df %>% 
   count(Location, Code) %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = n, 
                       values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

---

In base R, you can use `table` for that.

```
table(df$Code, df$Location)
```

Comment: this works but in my case this is not practical. my original data frame has millions of rows with hundreds of thousands different codes, thats why i would need the locations as columns or two different data frames, one for each location.

Comment: @Dutschke A visual representation of your output would have helped. Do you need `df %>%
  count(Location, Code) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))` ?

Comment: i am sorry, i still have to learn how stackoverflow works. i dont know how to present data frames. the code is exactly what i need. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution using Ronak's logic:

```
within(df, {
    n_vec <- as.numeric(ave(paste0(Location, Code), paste0(Location, Code), FUN = length))
    percent_vec <- ave(n_vec, Location, FUN = function(x){x / sum(n_vec)}) * 100
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `summarise` with `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Location, Code) %>%
     summarise(Percent = n()) %>% 
     mutate(Percent = Percent/sum(Percent) * 100)
```